# How to proxy an endpoint, using Google App Engine

Tags: google-app-engine, google-cloud-platform

I used to have an Nginx proxy that would do below :

```
location /api {
    proxy_pass  http://www.myapiexample.com;
  }
```

Then if I made a request to my website at `www.example.com/api`, it would take me to `http://www.myapiexample.com`.

With the app engine, and I'm using Nodejs as my backend, how I can achieve the same?

[Can't find anything in the docs](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/standard/python/config/appref)

---

**UPDATE** : If I'm understanding correctly, I can't have my `Nginx` anymore, so I need to find a way to have the same proxying functionality with App Engine.

Comment: @OliverAragon the fact that I can't :) I don't know how to do it,

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use `dispatch.yaml` configuration file if both of your web and api modules are on app engine. `dispatch.yaml` sends incoming requests to a specific service depending on the path or hostname in the URL.

```
dispatch:
  # Default service serves simple hostname request.
  - url: " example.com"
    service: default

  # Send all api traffic to the api backend.
  - url: "*/api/*"
    service: api-backend
```

You can read more about [how to use dispatch file](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/flexible/python/reference/dispatch-yaml).

If your api module is not on app engine you can redirect requests on application level

dispatch:

```
  # Send all api traffic to the api backend.
  - url: "*/api/*"
    script: router.py
```

You can write your routing code in router.py something like

```
class RouteHandler(webapp.RequestHandler):
    def get(self):
        self.redirect("http://www.myapiexample.com;", True)
```

Comment: I can't believe I missed this, I actually didn't read more than app.yaml, sadly I thought that's all there is to routing. Does this mean all my backend request are first gonna hit my frontend app engine, then be redirected/proxied to backend?
? If yes, is this a good practice in terms of scaling?

Comment: In normal flow App Engine's default routing applies to requests. Alternatively, you can use a dispatch file for your own rules.  See how requests are routed in App Engine https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/standard/python/how-requests-are-routed

Comment: It will not affect the scalability of the application